# How can I avoid labels on short lines?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a road map in QGIS (v 3.22.1). I want to put labels on the roads, but since  I get a label on each line segment there will be too many labels when there are many short segments, for example on highway crossing.

[image: Too many "E6" and "E134" - labels]

How can I avoid this? I am using a rule based labeling, so I thought

```
"vegkategori" = 'E' and length($geometry) > 2000
```

would stop labels on lines shorter than 2000m, but no. ($length neither did work).

Is there some other way of filtering out labels on short lines? - or what would be perfect - a minimum distance between labels on the same data set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a native feature in QGIS.
Select your layer, right-click > Properties > Label.
Then select `Rendering` and scroll down.

You will fine the wanted option (blue color on screenshot). A nice alternative would be to connect lines to prevent unwanted labels (green color on screenshot) `Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels`

[image: qgis label option]

Comment: I had checked Merge connected lines (...) and  unchecked the two others, I think itdid not have any effect since in the data layer the road mya be saved as several parallell lines  in those problematic cases. The "supress labeling (...)" did save my day.